# Why is my foundry test contract not deploying to the 0xb4c79daB8f259C7Aee6E5b2Aa729821864227e84 address?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, evm, foundry, forge

I was reading in the [docs](https://book.getfoundry.sh/forge/writing-tests) that the test address is deployed to `0xb4c79daB8f259C7Aee6E5b2Aa729821864227e84` yet when I try to `console.log(address(this))` inside of my test, I get returned a different address: (`0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496`).

Why is my test not deploying to that address?

Here is my entire test file:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

import "forge-std/Test.sol";
import "../src/Funding.sol";

contract FundingTest is Test {
    Funding public funding;

    function setUp() public {
       funding = new Funding(777);
       console.log(msg.sender);
    }

    function testConsoleLog() public view {
        console.log(address(this));
    }
}
```

Or am I misunderstanding the docs? Is it just using that address as an example to show you that the test contract address is also the deployer of your main contract inside the test?

Answer (score 2):

Your test contract is deployed to a different address than the one mentioned in the docs because each test contract has its own unique address. The address mentioned in the docs is just an example to show that the test contract address is also the deployer of your main contract inside the test.

When you run your tests, Solidity creates a new instance of your test contract and deploys it to a new address.

So, it is normal for you to see a different address when you `console.log(address(this))` in your test contract. This address belongs to the instance of your test contract that is deployed when you run your tests.

Comment: User asking you here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/153101

Answer (score 2):

@xana Sorry  address 0x7FA9385bE102ac3EAc297483Dd6233D62b3e1496 is consistent as for myself as well the same deployment address pops up

[image]

Comment: In the future, you need to get couple of reputation points so that you can properly post a comment instead of an answer.